# Restore quality from Whatsapp compressed picture

Tags: image, printing, whatsapp, image-compression

Whatsapp is famous for compressing images degrading their quality. I have a picture where unfortunately the original was lost and the only copy left was sent by WhatsApp.

Details of the picture are dimension 1200 x 1600 pixels, size 163 Kb, dpi 96. I would like to print it as crispy and as big as possible. I have already found an online tool to enhance dpi from 96 to 300. What other tricks are available to try to restore the original quality as much as possible? I clearly know that getting back to the original quality is impossible.